# std::exception не ловит исключения наследника

Tags: c++, исключения

Собственно:

```
#include <iostream>

class Exception : std::exception
{
public:
    Exception(const std::string &&whatStr) noexcept : whatStr(std::move(whatStr)) { }
    Exception(const std::string &whatStr) noexcept : whatStr(whatStr) { }
   ~Exception() noexcept=default;

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return whatStr.c_str();
    }

private:
    std::string whatStr;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    try
    {
      throw Exception("hello");
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout<< e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Так происходит `std::terminate`, потому что `exception& e` не ловит `Exception`.
Если добавить:

```
  catch(Exception& e)
    {
        std::cout<< e.what();
    }
```

То он понятное дело ловит. Но, почему не ловит базовый класс?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Предположу, проблема в том, что ваше наследование не публичное.

Попробуйте так:

```
class Exception : public std::exception
```

Только при открытом (`public`) наследовании код, обрабатывающий исключения, знает о том, что `Exception` — потомок `std::exception`.

---

Обязательная [нормативная ссылка](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#3): стандарт явно требует публичного наследования:

> the handler is of type *cv* `T` or *cv* `T&` and `T` is an unambiguous public base class of `E` [...]

Это, кстати, означает, что без публичного наследования код с отловом исключений не будет работать даже в функциях-членах класса `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте предупреждения компилятора, они рулез :)

VC++:

```
test.cpp(28): warning C4673: при передаче "Exception" следующие типы не будут рассматриваться на сайте получателя
test.cpp(28): warning C4670: exception: этот базовый класс недоступен
```

**exception: этот базовый класс недоступен**
Как справедливо заметил @VladD, нужно public-наследование

Comment: mingw, к сожалению, об этом умолчал

Comment: Что там по умолчанию с предупреждениями? Крайне рекомендую обязательно их включать - большинство простых ошибок (опечатки и т.п.) вылавливаются сразу же.

Comment: -Wpedantic
 -Wall
 -Wextra включены, вроде бы даже больше и нечего